# Python Databases of Variable Length Inputs

Tags: python, database, sqlite, openpyxl, python-3.9

Guten Morgen.

Im currently trying to compile a database in Python3.9 from an excel file. The idea is that I would have an excel file that I can more easily modify, then have a python script to convert that into a .db file for use in other scripts.

Now my first main issue is that the input data types have different amounts of input values. The smallest input length I have is 3 (Volts, V, mV) and an input of ~50 (I'm not going to throw it in its just a lot trust me). For a manual input of a database, I've been using '' as a placeholder for shorter inputs, but there has to be a better way, right? If there is, please let me know. Basic manual code attached at the bottom for a 14 length input array instead of the full 50 cause, ugh. Anyway, thanks in advance!

Edit: There are two primary issues that I have faced. The first (which has been resolved) is converting the inconsistent lengthed input from my Excel file. The second is initialising a database that can accept any length of data inputs. So if I had an excel input of 10 rows each comprising of 5 data points, or an excel input of 80 rows with 60 data points each. I'm hoping that there's a way that I can initialize the database so that I can easily accept either scenario, instead of having to hardcode a specific number of inputs.

```
con = sl.connect('793unitDB.db')

try:
    with con:
        con.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE USER (
                id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                unitName TEXT,
                unitType01 TEXT,
                unitType02 TEXT,
                unitType03 TEXT,
                unitType04 TEXT,
                unitType05 TEXT,
                unitType06 TEXT,
                unitType07 TEXT,
                unitType08 TEXT,
                unitType09 TEXT,
                unitType10 TEXT,
                unitType11 TEXT,
                unitType12 TEXT
            );
        """)
except:
    #print("Failed Initialisation")
    pass

sql = 'INSERT INTO USER (id, unitName, unitType01, unitType02, unitType03, unitType04, unitType05, unitType06, unitType07, unitType08, unitType09, unitType10, unitType11, unitType12) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
data = [
    (1, 'Length', 'cm', 'ft', 'in', 'km', 'm', 'micron', 'µm', 'mile', 'mm', 'nm', '', ''),
    (2, 'Force', 'DaM', 'dyn', 'gf', 'kgf', 'kip', 'nK', 'lbf', 'mN', 'MT', 'N', 'ozf', 'MN'),
    (3, 'Time', 'h', 'min', 'ms', 's', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''),
    (4, 'Volts', 'V', 'mV', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
]
try: 
    with con:
        con.executemany(sql, data)
except: 
    pass

with con:
    data = con.execute("SELECT * FROM USER ")
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Excel file as an intermediate format they you will have no problem with rows of uneven lenght as `ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=50, values_only=True)` always give you tuples that have 50 values.

You can use the same approach when working directly: simply create a list of 50 items and overwrite as a many items as you can.

```
data = [
    (1, 'Length', 'cm', 'ft', 'in', 'km', 'm', 'micron', 'µm', 'mile', 'mm', 'nm', '', ''),
    (2, 'Force', 'DaM', 'dyn', 'gf', 'kgf', 'kip', 'nK', 'lbf', 'mN', 'MT', 'N', 'ozf', 'MN'),
    (3, 'Time', 'h', 'min', 'ms', 's', ),
    (4, 'Volts', 'V', 'mV', )
]

rows = []
for item in data:
    row = [""]*50
    row[:len(item)] = item
    rows.append(row)

con.executemany(sql, rows)
```

Your other question seems to be about dynamically creating the schema and insert statements. This is easy enough to do but you might be better using the `Array` data type if your database supports it. Dynamically creating SQL statements **always** carries a risk of SQL injection with it but look at using `zfill` if you want to pursue this.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can I use a method like this for the DB initialization as well?
So far I've got an input file with 82 rows, with the longest row having 60 strings, so my resulting data[] is [82][61]. 
Or, do I need to initialize the DB with 61 fixed rows and go from there?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please edit your initial question to provide more information.

Comment: Sorry, I hope that I clarified the issue that I've hit in this script.